# Example of ObjectAnimator to animate a part of a String from a TextView

Tags: android, android-animation, android-view, textview

As I mentioned on the title. Is there a sufficient way to say which part of the string you want to animate?
I've tried to find out and I hope you all can give me an advice to solve it?

I am a little lost, and I haven't explored the ObjectAnimator API yet but I hope that someone out there can guide me to use ObjectAnimator and TextView to animate a given word from the TextView.

For example: "Hello World Android", now I want to fade out and fade in the word "World".

Example code:

```
  public static void fadeEnhancedText(Context context,, TextView labEnchangedText) {
        //animation add objectanimation 
        //MUST BE A WAY TO EXTRACT THE WORD
       mAnimationSet.play(fadeIn(labEnchangedText)).after(fadeOut(labEnchangedText));
       mAnimationSet.start();
    }

    private static ObjectAnimator fadeIn(TextView textView)
    {

        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "alpha",0f,1f);
        animation.setDuration(500);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(41, 41, 41));
        return animation;

    }

    private static ObjectAnimator fadeOut(final TextView textView)
    {
        final int defaultColor = textView.getCurrentTextColor();
        textView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(177, 24, 46));
        ObjectAnimator animation = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(textView, "alpha",1f,0f);
        animation.addListener(new Animator.AnimatorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                textView.setTextColor(defaultColor);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationCancel(Animator animation) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animator animation) {

            }
        });
        animation.setRepeatCount(4);
        animation.setDuration(1000);
        return animation;

    }
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?

Comment: for example: "Hello Android World", from a TextView. I want to Animate fade out/fade in with another color on the word Android and that only

Comment: edited my post , I hope there will be someone who can help me